# How to SUM CASE Something Other Than the Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Want to find the count of a non-PK attribute (varchar), which utilizes a case. Wondering how to achieve this? Let's call this attribute 'code'

If I were doing it on the PK it would be something like:

```
SELECT
   sum(case when xx1 = 'apples' and xx2 = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as my_count 
from fruits
```

Sorry I should mention that there are far less 'code' values than PKs, so it wouldn't be 1 to 1 in terms of count.

EDIT: Let's say there are 20 PK_IDs (fruit_id), which satisfy xx1 = 'apples' and xx2 = 5 in fruits. My query above would pull that. There are only 6 codes though that satisfy those same 2 filters in fruits. I would want my query to return a value of 6.

Comment: Have you tried that query?

Comment: first of all how can xxx be both apples and 5?

Comment: second of all why would a PK have any impact? -- every field should act the same.

Comment: To clarify your question could you please add some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what we are trying to achieve,  but it sounds like you might be after a count of distinct values ...

Consider a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f.xx1)
  FROM fruits f
```

if the values in the xx1 column of all rows are either 'apples' or 'oranges', then COUNT(DISTINCT  will return 2.

We can apply that pattern to a CASE expression, conditional aggregation just like the SUM() is getting a count of rows.

Where we don't want to "count" a value, we can return NULL in place of a value.

Consider:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN f.xx1='apples' AND f.xx2=5 THEN f.code ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_dist_code
     , COUNT(         CASE WHEN f.xx1='apples' AND f.xx2=5 THEN   1    ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_rows
  FROM fruits f
```

---

I'm just guessing at what we are trying to achieve. Consider including some sample data and example of the output to be returned, to help explain the specification.

Comment: `else null` is superfluous. Apart from that, I understand the question like you do, so your answer should produce the expected results.

Comment: @GMB,  yes, the `ELSE NULL` can be omitted; the effect is the same as if we had specified `ELSE NULL`. The important point is that the `COUNT()` aggregate does not get increment for NULL values.  (Some readers may not be familiar with the behavior of `CASE` when the `ELSE` is omitted; that's the main reason I included it.) The example query in this answer does satisfy one possible interpretation of the specification.